# What's the easiest way to factor $5^{10} - 1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, prime-factorization

What's the easiest way to factor $5^{10} - 1$?

I believe $5 - 1$ is a factor based off the binomial theorem. 
From there I do not know. 
We are using congruence's in this class.

Comment: $$5^{10}-1\\
\implies (5^5+1)(5^5-1)\\
\implies (5^5+1)(5^{2.5}+1)(5^{2.5}-1)$$?

Comment: @Sanath - I think he wants this factored into integers.

Comment: Without doing any formal math,
$$5^{10}-1=9765624=2^3 \times 3 \times 11 \times 71 \times 521$$

Comment: This is for a practice exam in which there is no calculators so doing large computations may not be the most efficient way to solve this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider $x^{10} - 1.$

The first trivial factorization is $(x^5-1)(x^5+1)$.

Note that $1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4 = \frac{x^5-1}{x-1}$ by the geometric series formula.

Secondly, replace $x$ with $-x$ to see that $1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4 = \frac{x^5+1}{x+1}.$

$$x^{10} - 1 = (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)(1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4)(x-1)(x+1).$$

It should be easy to factor $5^{10} - 1$ into $4\times 6\times 781 \times 521.$

Another trick is to see that $11$ clearly divides $781$ because $7+1 = 8$ (cf. multiplying by $11$ shortcuts).

Simple division gives us $$\boxed{5^{10} - 1 = 2^3 \times 3 \times 11 \times 71 \times 521}.$$

The only thing left is to show that $521$ is prime.

All we have to check is primes less than $\sqrt{521}$ because if there are factors other than $1$ and $521$ it must be less than (or equal to) $\sqrt{521}$. (Note that $23^2 = 529$).

Clearly $2,3,5$ and $ 11$ do not work so now we must check $7, 13, 17$ and $19$.

$7$ does not work because if $7$ divided $521$ it would divide $521-21 = 500$.

$13$ does not work because $521-26 = 495 = 99\times5$.

$17$ does not work because $521-17*3 = 470 = 47\times10$.

$19$ does not work because $521-19*9 = 350 = 35\times10$.

I found these terms to subtract by trying to eliminate the $1$ at the end of $571$ by turning it into a $5$ or a $0$.

Comment: Depending on how much number theory you are allowed to assume, you can also note, in advance, that Fermat's Little Theorem implies $11$ *must* be a prime divisor, so once you get it to $4\times6\times781\times521$ you know $11$ divides one of the two big numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Note that
$$
5^{10} - 1 = (5^5+1)(5^5-1)
$$
And that
$$
5^5-1 = (5 - 1)(5^4 + 5^3 + 5^2 + 5 + 1)\\
5^5+1 = (5+1)(5^4 - 5^3 + 5^2 - 5 + 1)
$$
That should give you a fairly good start. We cannot factor this further using formal factorization alone.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the fact that $x^n-1=(x-1)(1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-1})$

so here $5^{10}-1=(5-1)(1+5+5^2+5^3+...+5^9)$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of factorization or congruence information your are looking for, the question isn't very clear. But here is an easy congruence observation about your number:

We know that 
$$
\sum_{k=0}^9 5^k=\frac{5^{10}-1}{5-1}=\frac{5^{10}-1}{4},
$$
thus
$$
4\cdot\sum_{k=0}^9 5^k=5^{10}-1.
$$
It is clear that $\sum_{k=0}^9 5^k\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and so we conclude that $4\sum_{k=0}^9 5^k\equiv 4\pmod 5$.

You could also use a nested parenthesis "factorization" based on the above and get that 
$$
4(5(5(5(5(5(5(5(5(5+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1)+1).
$$